# Lubuntu 18.04 grub EFI problem

Tags: grub2, lubuntu, uefi

When I installed Lubuntu 18.04 alongside 16.04 and 14.04 it went OK apart from installing grub at the end. When switching on, I chose an entry from the hardware's boot device menu and it didn't work. I then chose the EFI entry and it worked OK.

But installing applications fails in shim-signed (`/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh` doesn't exist) and grub-efi-amd64-signed (cannot find EFI directory)

The applications launch and working OK, but scripts that include installing are thrown by the errors. I don't think I have an EFI process (?) or a need for one.

How can I unscramble this without starting from scratch ?

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
$ sudo apt remove shim-signed grub-efi-amd64-signed
```

seems to fix it.